# Not Inserting Data into Array

Tags: insert, heap, priority-queue

I am writing this insert function that adds a String to my double-ended priority queue. However I keep getting an

```
ArrayIndexOutOfBounds:0
```

error. I keep seem to figure out what is wrong.

Here is my code:

```
public void insert(String data) {
    this.queue[heapSize++] = data;
    this.ensureCapacity(heapSize);
    this.upwardHeapify(heapSize -1);
}
```

Comment: You're not checking if `heapSize` exceeds the array capacity. That *could* be it but we can't be certain since you haven't given us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You probably want to call `ensureCapacity` *before* you add the item to the array. Swap the first two lines of your function.